# Send String over UDP;Receive it, Concatenate it and Send it Back

Tags: java, string, udp, concatenation

I am trying to build a simple UDP server in which receives a String, adds on a ":" + integer value to the String and sends it back as so:

```
    while(true)
    {
        buffer = new byte[10000];
        DatagramPacket request= new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
        asocket.receive(request);
        byte[] data=request.getData();
        String stringData= new String(data);
        System.out.println(stringData);
        System.out.println(seqNumber);
        stringData+=":" + seqNumber;
        System.out.println(stringData);
        DatagramPacket output = new DatagramPacket(stringData.getBytes(),stringData.getBytes().length,group,9005); 
        broadcastSocket.send(output);
        seqNumber++;
    }
```

The issue is when printing out the variable stringData it never concatenates the : + integer value.Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. So without doing that its adding a bunch of white space to the String?

Comment: Alright thank you so much, it works now!